# mysql and python error with columns

Tags: python, mysql

I am running mysql on python 3.3 and when a bunch of requests come in at the same time it updates all rows of the table to that value instead of just where the where clause says
 The part of the code seems to be erroring is:

```
mdbe=mysql.connector.connect(user=user,password=password,database=database).cursor(buffered=True).execute
us="hi"
mdbe('update blas set setter="%s",blanks="%s",lastblank="%s" where us="%s"'%(setter,blanker,a,us)),mconn.commit()
```

that should make it so only the row with the us="hi" will change but it makes all rows change.

Comment: The example code is not.. Python. Please rewrite.

Comment: I ended up removing it and completly rewriting, its python just using a mysql python connector